# Bag with $3$ black balls and $5$ white balls

Tags: probability, statistics

> We have a bag with $3$ black balls and $5$ white balls. What is the probability of picking out two white balls if at least one of them is white?

If $A$ is the event of first ball being white and $B$ the second ball being white, could it be $p\bigl((A|B)\cup(B|A)\bigr)$?
Although $B$ depends on $A$, I don't understand why $A$ depends on $B$, as $B$ occurs after $A$ has occurred.

Thank you very much for your help.

Edit: and the probability of obtaining two white balls if I have only one white (regardless if it’s the first or the second one)?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try using Bayes' theorem

Comment: You are asked for the conditional probability that both balls are white given that at least one ball is white, so you need to divide the probability that both balls are white by the probability that at least one of the two balls is white.

Comment: Your suggested $p\bigl((A\mid B)\cup(B\mid A)\bigr)$ is not actually meaningful as $A\mid B$ and $B\mid A$ are not events (at least not in the same probability space)  so do not have a union

Comment: @Sergio You seek $P(A\cap B\mid A\cup B)$, the probability for both events occur when given one or the other does.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula for conditional probability $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ we can solve this problem. Denote $A$ as the event that both balls are white, and $B$ as the event that at least $1$ is white. Assuming we pick the balls out without replacement, we have that $$P(A\cap B)=\frac{5}{8}\frac{4}{7}=\frac{5}{14}$$

Then, the probability that we pick at least one white ball is just the opposite of the event of picking all black balls. So $$P(B)=1-\frac{3}{8}\frac{2}{7}=1-\frac{3}{28}=\frac{25}{28}$$

Hence, $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{5}{14}}{\frac{25}{28}}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

> If A is the event of first ball being white and B the second ball being white, could it be p((A|B)∪(B|A))?

That makes no sense.  There is only ever one bar in a conditional probability, separating the event being measured and the condition over which the probability is measured.

You seek $P(A\cap B\mid A\cup B)$, the probability for both events occur when given one or the other does.  Use Bayes' Rule$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid A\cup B)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap(A\cup B))}{\mathsf P(A\cup B)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(A\cup B)}\end{align}$$

> Although B depends on A, I don't understand why A depends on B, as B occurs after A has occurred.

Think of it in terms of knowledge and confidence of the unknown.  Probability is a measure of an event's occurrence given some knowledge; whether that is "will occur" or "has occurred".  The timing of the process does not matter, just what you know about the results.

So: if you know that a white ball *will* be drawn on the second draw, how confident would you be about a white ball being drawn on the first draw?  You also know that this is drawing without replacement, so if the second draw *will* be white, *that* white ball cannot be the one drawn on the first draw.